# Bitmap drawable not work on Android < 5

Tags: android

I'm try to make a color icon by bitmap drawable on the Menu. I've download the icon from https://www.google.com/design/icons/

Here is my drawable  ic_menu_search.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
  android:dither="true"
  android:tileMode="repeat"
  android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

Here is my menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

The color:

```
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#0072c6</color>
```

It's work perfect on Android 5.0 and above, the icon display in #0072c6 color. But on Android < 5.0 it's still black as default.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tint in drawables](http://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html#DrawableTint) is available since API 21:

You could use ColorOverlay for lower APIs:

```
// Add a 50% transparent black color on top of the original
drawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#80000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Great, it's work, just wonder why the AS didn't show warning when I try to wrote a function which support for old version hmmm.